# How to add alternate exchange while defining binding url?

Tags: jms, qpid

I need to create queue on application start and should delete when application stop. Also messages need to reroute to alternate exchange on application shutdown. How can we add alternate exchange option in the [Binding URL](https://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-java-6.1.6/jms-client-0-8/book/JMS-Client-0-8-Binding-URL.html)? I am using Java Qpid client 6.1.0 and JMS 1.1.

Binding URL:

```
topic://ToApp.Ex/test.queue?routingkey='#.am.#'&durable='false'&autodelete='true'&exclusive='false'
```

Answer (score 1):

I able to create a queue and connect to alternate exchange using address string.

address string is as below.

queue.name;{assert: always, node:{x-declare: {alternate-exchange: 'Forwarder.Ex', auto-delete:True },  x-bindings: [{ exchange: 'ToApp.Ex', key: '#.am.#' }], type: queue }, create: always, delete: always}

Thanks